# Constructing Firestore references model in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to avoid typing strings while coding to get access to my documents in Firestore. I've been trying to put together some code that can be reusable throughout the project and avoid errors.

I've put together this enum that points to different collections in Firestore and so far it is working as expected though I would like to be able to enhance it with the sub collection pointers.

Here is the code which I have in place

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

enum FirestoreReference {

    case products(uid: String)
    case stores

    func collectionRef() -> CollectionReference {
        switch self {
        case .stores:
            return Firestore.firestore().collection(path)
        case .products(uid: let uid):
            return Firestore.firestore().collection(path).document(uid).collection("products")
        }
    }

    private var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .products:
            return "stores"
        case .stores:
            return "stores"
        }
    }
}
```

Previously if I wanted to access my sub collection I would have to type

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("stores").document(storeId).collection("products")
```

When I implemented the above I can access the sub collection using the following line, where storeId is retrieved using FirebaseAuth and products collection is a sub collection of the stores collection.

```
FirestoreReference.products(uid: storeId).collectionRef()
```

Is there a better way to structure this? Maybe a was also to extend it to access documents?

Comment: The question is very unclear and while we love to see code on questions, showing us an enum without context isn't helpful. Can you please edit your question and clarify what you're asking, include the code you've attempted and what the expected outcome is?

Comment: Hi Jay, thank you. you actually made me think it further and its now working though would there be a better way to do it? I've amended the question as you've said.

Comment: It's not critical but keep in mind that uid = User Id and a uid ties back to a specific user. You can name vars anything you want but for readability it's a tad confusing. It's really attempting to use that enum as a singleton pattern but it doesn't fit every case - what if you want to read a specific document, or perform a query, or add listener to a collection that you want to remove later `let listener = db.collection("cities").addSnapshotListener` for example. Not sure what the use case is specifically but it doesn't seem it will save any typing.